# Using jQuery Validator on dialog displayed with BlockUI

Tags: asp.net, jquery-validate, jquery-blockui

I'm still learning jQuery, and I've come up against something I'm not sure how to proceed with.

I have a form, within it is a div which is hidden (using "display: none") at load time.  This div is later displayed via the BlockUI plugin as a modal dialog for the editing of certain input elements.  I'm trying to get the validation plugin to check that the fields I have denoted as required are actually filled in by the end user.

I have used the validation plugin elsewhere in my app without any problems, but this is the first time I'm using it to validate inputs that are hidden at load time.  The validations aren't being executed (i.e. empty text inputs that are marked as required aren't flagged as such, and .valid() returns true).

I stepped through the validation logic with Firebug and discovered that none of the input elements within the dialog div are present within $(this.currentForm).  If I keep the dialog div visible and remove the $.blockUI call, then the validation works as expected.

So I think I know what the problem is now -- my inputs aren't in the DOM, because they were originally not visible, so the validation plugin doesn't know they exist.  I'm not sure how to fix this.  Can anyone offer a suggestion?   Thanks!

EDIT: The call to $.blockUI() is removing the dialog div from the DOM.  Looks like I'll have to find another way to display the dialog.

EDIT: the code is proprietary so I can't post it.

[Validation plug-in link](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

[BlockUI plug-in link](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/)

Comment: Can you supply some code and a link to the plug-in you are using?

Comment: BlockUI plug-in: [link](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/)   Validation plug-in: [link](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)  I've resorted to doing the validation manually for now.